# D3 Sunburst clip path of text

Tags: svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to implement a d3 visualization based on the sunburst diagram, and i have found an almost perfect online example of this which i have got working 
http://tributary.io/inlet/4127332/:

[image]

My main issue is that I need to also Clip the text to the segment,I have tried using the svg clip path but my meager d3 skills have let me down. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: If you were able to put in the code you tried that didn't work it might help d3 gurus help you more effectively ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my first attempt to clip the text did not work and I think this is because the arc's coordinate space does not line up with the text's coordinate space in the way that you want if you are using the arc generator, as you are.

I found that if I apply the clip to the groups you make for each node then it worked like a charm. There was one caveat. When I tried generating my clip path and then applying them the order that the nodes were joined to the elements differed and so the wrong path were clipping the wrong text. I got around this by adding an id to each data element. You can see the final version [here](http://tributary.io/inlet/5200169)

The important parts are adding the clip paths (note the use of the new id field):

```
svg.append('defs')
   .selectAll("clipPath")
   .data(partition.nodes)
   .enter().append('svg:clipPath')
   .attr('id', function(d,i) { return d.id;})
   .append('path').attr('d', arc);
```

Then you simply have to reference them on your node groups (again using the id):

```
group = 
   svg.selectAll("g")
   .data(partition.nodes)
   .enter().append('svg:g')
   .attr('clip-path', function(d,i) { return 'url(#' + d.id + ')';});
```

In the tributary I put the svg data join first so that the "defs" node would appear in the usual place (first after the svg tag), but I do not think this is technically necessary.